# std::getline fails at reading file via ifstream

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I created this piece of code (using C++11 standards):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string input;
    cout << "Enter the name of a file:\n";
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << "Reading file...\n";
    ifstream readstream(input);
    if (!readstream.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error while opening file\n";
        return 0;
    } else {
        string currentln;
        while (getline(readstream, currentln)) {
             cout << currentln;
        }
        return 0;
   }
}
```

I compiled this code with the mingw-w64 implementation of GCC, with this command:

```
gcc -std=c++11 read.cpp -o read.exe
```

It compiled successfully, however, when I run it:

```
Enter the name of a file:
example.txt
Reading file...
```

And then nothing. It doesn't output any characters of the file. The file does exist, and it doesn't have any problems opening it. However, when I compile and run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string input;
    cout << "Enter the name of a file:\n";
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << "Reading file...\n";
    ifstream readstream(input);
    if (!readstream.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error while opening file\n";
        return 0;
    } else {
        char currentchar;
        while (!readstream.eof()) {
          while(readstream.get(currentchar)) {
               cout << currentchar;
          }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It works.
I compiled it the same way:

```
g++ -std=c++11 read.cpp -o read.exe
```

But instead of using getline(), I used ifstream.get();

Can anyone tell me why getline() does not work in this situation?

Comment: "It compiled successfully" - I sincerely doubt that. Perhaps point out the specific overload of `std::getline` you think should execute with `while (getline(readstream, currentchar))`. [Here is the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Short answer: there is no overload of `std::getline` that uses a `char` for the second parameter. I.e. you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah, ok. That was an error in my typing. I'll fix that. But even when I use a string instead of a char, it fails.

Comment: I suspect there is no endline characters anywhere in the file... but that's just an idea

Comment: Now changed, this code is *begging* for a debugger in your environment. I see nothing blatantly wrong with the code you state doesn't work. presuming your input filename is a text file reachable from whatever relative or absolute path (if any) you're providing, it should work. A debugger and single-stepping is your best next move.

Comment: I tried your first code and it worked fine. What does example.txt look like?

Comment: Well, apparently it works. Wow. It didn't before. Although now I am running Windows 10 and when I tried it I was running Windows 8.1. I wonder if that was the cause.